# Pandas: merge miscellaneous keys into the "others" row

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame like this

```
DataFrame({"key":["a","b","c","d","e"], "value": [5,4,3,2,1]})
```

I am mainly interested in row "a", "b" and "c". I want to merge everything else into an "others" row like this

```
      key  value
0       a      5
1       b      4
2       c      3
3  others      3
```

I wonder how can this be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a dataframe without d and e:

```
df2 = df[df.key.isin(["a","b","c"])]
```

Then find the value that you want the other column to have (using the sum function in this example):

```
val = df[~df["key"].isin(["a","b","c"])].sum()["value"]
```

Finally, append this column to the second df:

```
df2.append({"key":"others", "value":val},ignore_index=True)
```

df2 is now:

```
      key value
0       a     5
1       b     4
2       c     3
3  others     3
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do it. Not sure if it is the best way.

```
In [3]: key_map = {"a":"a", "b":"b", "c":"c"}   
In [4]: data['key1'] = data['key'].map(lambda k: key_map.get(k, "others"))    
In [5]: data.groupby("key1").sum()
Out[5]:
        value
key1
a           5
b           4
c           3
others      3
```